# How to start a stopped docker container and add additional flags?

Tags: docker, containers

So I have a docker container running a Jupyter Lab environment, and I would like to be able to access a postgres database on the host machine from within the container. It looks like this is possible if when the container is created you use the flag `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`, but this wasn't a requirement at the time. Is it possible to stop the container and add that parameter somehow to `docker start`? Quite a bit has been installed in the container since it was created, so if I can avoid having to create a new container I'd like to.

I've tried adding the `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` parameter to the `docker start` command, but received the message that `--add-host` is an unknown flag.

Comment: The default IP of the Docker host is `172.17.0.1`, you can connect using this ip, or you can customize it on docker compose yaml, on `networks:` section.